# Where do I set checkreferences on the JOB POST?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Reading the following documentation:

To create references for a composite design in Model Derivative. The description of references is stored in Model Derivative. To use it with the POST job endpoint, you need to set **checkReferences** to true.

(Extracted from here)
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/

Looking at the documentation for the POST JOB:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

CTRL + F "checkReferences" = 0 results.
(I read the Request Body Structure entirely... could not find that...)

Where do I put this checkreferences?

Where is "checkreferences" in the "POST JOB" documentation? (Besides the reference on "urn references")

Comment: I'm consulting our engineering team regarding the use of the `checkreferences` parameter. According to our tutorial, it's a part of the input parameter of the POST job indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tutorial described, the `checkreferences` parameter is part of the input. It's used for checking references of the input design and works for all supported formats. If file references are not created in advance, this parameter will be ignored by our API service according to our engineering team.

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LmlhbQ",
     "checkReferences": true //!<<< Here
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "stl",
         "advanced": {
           "format": "binary",
           "exportColor": true,
           "exportFileStructure": "multiple"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```